# Error "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements" after execute the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlexception

I'm getting the error on the title when trying to execute the  stored procedure
"{"Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.\r\nTransaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0."}"

```
SET ansi_nulls ON
go

SET quoted_identifier ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Updatepayments] @FileBank       VARCHAR(max),
                                       @CreatedBy      INT,
                                       @RequestPayment VARCHAR(max) out
AS
  BEGIN
      BEGIN try
          SET nocount ON;
          SET XACT_ABORT ON;

          BEGIN TRANSACTION

          SET @RequestPayment = '';

          DECLARE @line           VARCHAR(max),
                  @RequestId      INT,
                  @PaymentId      BIGINT,
                  @companyCode    VARCHAR(max),
                  @bankCode       VARCHAR(max),
                  @Date           VARCHAR(max),
                  @sumAmount      VARCHAR(max),
                  @recordCount    VARCHAR(max),
                  @bankBranchCode VARCHAR(max),
                  @ChanalCode     VARCHAR(max),
                  @PaymentDate    VARCHAR(max),
                  @billNumber     VARCHAR(max),
                  @paymentNumber  VARCHAR(max),
                  @TrackNumber    VARCHAR(max),
                  @PaymentExtra   VARCHAR(max),
                  @Amount         VARCHAR(max),
                  @CurrentStageId INT,
                  @NextStageId    INT,
                  @ErrorMsg       VARCHAR(max),
                  @ErrorNumber    INT,
                  @ErrorProc      SYSNAME,
                  @ErrorLine      INT;


          DECLARE req_cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT *
            FROM   Splitstring(@FileBank, Char(10));

          OPEN req_cursor;

          FETCH next FROM req_cursor INTO @line

          SET @companyCode=Substring(@FileBank, 1, 4);
          SET @bankCode=Substring(@FileBank, 5, 2);
          SET @Date=Substring(@FileBank, 7, 6);
          SET @sumAmount=Substring(@FileBank, 13, 16);
          SET @recordCount=Substring(@FileBank, 29, 8);
          SET @Amount = 0;

          FETCH next FROM req_cursor INTO @line

          WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @bankBranchCode=Substring(@line, 1, 6);
                SET @ChanalCode=Substring(@line, 7, 2)
                SET @PaymentDate=( CASE
                                     WHEN Cast(Substring(@line, 9, 2) AS INT) <
                                          99
                                   THEN
                                     '14' + Substring(@line, 9, 6)
                                     ELSE '13' + Substring(@line, 9, 6)
                                   END );
                SET @billNumber =Cast(Cast(Substring(@line, 15, 18) AS BIGINT)AS
                                      VARCHAR(max));
                SET @paymentNumber=Cast(Cast(Substring(@line, 33, 18) AS BIGINT)
                                        AS
                                        VARCHAR
                                        (
                                        max));
                SET @TrackNumber=Substring(@line, 51, 6);
                SET @PaymentExtra=Substring(@line, 57, 13);
                SET @Amount = 0;

                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM   [dbo].[bankaccountinfo]
                           WHERE  companycode = @companyCode)
                  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
                            FROM   [dbo].[payment]
                            WHERE  billnumber = @billNumber
                                   AND paymentnumber = @paymentNumber)
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @RequestId = requestid,
                               @PaymentId = paymentid,
                               @Amount = Cast(Cast(amount AS BIGINT)AS
                                              VARCHAR(max))
                        FROM   payment
                        WHERE  billnumber = @billNumber
                               AND paymentnumber = @paymentNumber;

                        SELECT @CurrentStageId = lastexecutedstageid
                        FROM   vrequest
                        WHERE  requestid = @RequestId;

                        -- Fix empty values to null in order to set the null to 0
                        SET @billNumber = CASE
                                            WHEN @billNumber = '' THEN NULL
                                            ELSE @billNumber
                                          END
                        SET @paymentNumber = CASE
                                               WHEN @paymentNumber = '' THEN
                                               NULL
                                               ELSE @paymentNumber
                                             END
                        SET @Amount = CASE
                                        WHEN @Amount = '' THEN NULL
                                        ELSE @Amount
                                      END
                        SET @bankBranchCode = CASE
                                                WHEN @bankBranchCode = '' THEN
                                                NULL
                                                ELSE @bankBranchCode
                                              END
                        SET @TrackNumber = CASE
                                             WHEN @TrackNumber = '' THEN NULL
                                             ELSE @TrackNumber
                                           END
                        SET @ChanalCode = CASE
                                            WHEN @ChanalCode = '' THEN NULL
                                            ELSE @ChanalCode
                                          END
                        SET @RequestPayment = @RequestPayment + ( CASE
                                                                    WHEN
                                              @RequestPayment = ''
                                                                  THEN
                                                                    ''
                                                                    ELSE ','
                                                                  END ) + ( CASE
                                              WHEN
                                              EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                                     FROM   payment
                                                     WHERE
                                              paymentid = @PaymentId
                                              AND ispaid = 0) THEN
                                              '1'
                                              ELSE
                                              '2'
                                                                            END
                                              )
                                              +
                                              '|' +
                                              Isnull
                                              (
                                              @billNumber, 0) + '|' +
                                                                    Isnull(
                                              @paymentNumber,
                                                                    0
                                                                    ) +
                                              '|'
                                              +
                                              Isnull(@Amount, 0) + '|'
                                              + ( Isnull(@bankBranchCode, 0) ) +
                                              '|' +
                                              (
                                              Isnull(
                                              @TrackNumber, 0) ) + '|' +
                                              ( Isnull(@ChanalCode, 0) );

                        UPDATE [dbo].[payment]
                        SET    [ispaid] = 1,
                               [paymentdate] = Cast(dbo.S2m(@PaymentDate) AS
                                                    DATETIME)
                               ,
                               [retrivalrefrencenumber] =
                               @TrackNumber
                        WHERE  paymentid = @PaymentId
                               AND ispaid = 0;

                        SET @NextStageId = ( CASE @CurrentStageId
                                               WHEN 8 THEN 700
                                               WHEN 1 THEN 2
                                               WHEN 25 THEN 2
                                               ELSE 0
                                             END );

                        IF ( @NextStageId = 1
                              OR @NextStageId = 25 )
                          BEGIN
                              EXECUTE [dbo].[Addrequestexecutestage]
                                @RequestId,
                                2,
                                1,
                    'دریافت سیستمی اطلاعات پرداخت'
                          END
                    END
                  ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @RequestPayment = @RequestPayment + ( CASE
                                                                    WHEN
                                              @RequestPayment = ''
                                                                  THEN
                                                                    ''
                                                                    ELSE ','
                                                                  END ) + '3|' +
                                              Isnull(@billNumber, 0)
                                              + '|' +
                        Isnull(
                                      @paymentNumber, 0)
                                              +
                                              '|'
                                              +
                                              Isnull(
                                              @Amount, 0) + '|' + (
                                                                    Isnull(
                                              @bankBranchCode
                                                                    ,
                                                                    0) )
                                              +
                                              '|' +
                                              (
                                                                    Isnull(
                                              @TrackNumber, 0
                                                                    )
                                              ) +
                                              '|'
                                              + (
                                              Isnull(@ChanalCode, 0) );
                    END

                FETCH next FROM req_cursor INTO @line;
            END

          CLOSE req_cursor;

          DEALLOCATE req_cursor;

          COMMIT
      END try

      BEGIN catch
          SELECT @ErrorMsg = Error_message(),
                 @ErrorNumber = Error_number(),
                 @ErrorProc = Error_procedure(),
                 @ErrorLine = Error_line();

          ROLLBACK TRAN;

          INSERT INTO [dbo].[errorlog]
                      (errormsg,
                       errornumber,
                       errorproc,
                       errorline)
          VALUES      (@ErrorMsg,
                       @ErrorNumber,
                       @ErrorProc,
                       @ErrorLine)
      END catch
  END
```

Comment: Inside the `CATCH`, you should always do `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK`, because the transaction can be rolled back implicitly, and in fact if you use `XACT_ABORT` almost certainly is rolled back implicitly. Finally, take care that some errors abort the batch and doom the transaction, meaning it is no longer possible to perform `INSERT` statements. Unfortunately, this is also the case precisely when you use `XACT_ABORT`. See [here](https://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html) (and the rest of the series).